# Контейнер коллекция применение в С#

Tags: c#, .net, коллекции

Читаю Тролсена про обобщенные типы коллекций, и там используется терминология контейнер и коллекция вперемешку. У меня не отложилось 100% разделение между этими понятиями относительно с#, чуть ниже приведен код С++ там есть и контейнер и коллекция.

Погуглил википедию вывел следующее:

**Коллекция** в программировании — программный объект, содержащий в себе, тем или иным образом, набор значений одного или различных типов, и позволяющий обращаться к этим значениям.

**Конте́йнер** в программировании — структура (АТД), позволяющая инкапсулировать в себе объекты любого типа. Объектами (переменными) контейнеров являются коллекции, которые уже могут содержать объекты одного определённого типа.

Например, в языке C++, std::list (шаблонный класс) является контейнером, а объект его класса-конкретизации (англ. instantiation), как, например, std::list my_list является коллекцией.

В с# про коллекции я понял так

```
List<int> moreInts = new List<int>();//коллекция int
//List<T>//тоже коллекция обобщенная.
```

**Вопрос про контейнеры:**
Обобщенная коллекция и есть контейнер или контейнер пространство имен (System.Collection.Generic) или контейнеры мы сами пишем(представляя класс)?

Приведете пример контейнера и как именно они используются в .NET c#. Спасибо!

ПыСы: вот ссылка с общими ответами в конце обсуждения - контейнеров(в явном виде) в с# нет(как я понял), а есть только обобщенные(System.Collection.Generic) и необобщенные(System.Collection) коллекции. http://forum.vingrad.ru/forum/topic-307998/view-all.html#st_0_view_0

Comment: Скорее всего дело в переводе. Лучше читать в оригинале, тогда такие проблемы вряд ли возникнут.

Answer (score 5):

В C# не используют термин **Container** для описания структур данных, таких как List, Dictionary и т.д. Обычно, всё это называют коллекциями. В первую очередь это относится к классам из пространств имен (System.Collection.Generic) и (System.Collection). Говоря про обычные массивы, их также относят к коллекциям.

Что касается термина **Container**, его чаще применяют в контексте некоторых шаблонов проектирования, например, DI или IoC  контейнеры.

Так или иначе, это всего лишь вопросы терминологии.